# How do I remove these kinds of results from my Google searches?

Tags: google-search

These kinds of results are really annoying to see as they're in pure white.

I'm using stylish to style the rest of the Google page but I can't figure out to style this portion so I'm resorting to try and remove it.

How would I do that?[image]